# Mutate mean() is not computing average correctly?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm only able to replicate this example with the dataset I'm working on but I'm getting strange behavior using Mutate= mean(xx). Here's my code out of context:

```
data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(TP = mean(tp1:tp4),
         OCB= mean(ocb1:ocb4),
         GL= mean(gl1:gl4),
         JP= mean(tp1:gl4))
```

When I take a look at the averages, they all look good. I was going over my work and decided to compute means using SPSS and realized that my means for the above columns I mutated are incorrect (there are 2-3 that are off by an entire digit, delta of 1 -- out of n=120). This is a huge error especially since I'm only asking it to compute a mean.

The data are all clean and I have no missing data. Can anyone give me an idea why mutate would be so off? Again, 95% of the means are accurate, only 5% are off (not a rounding error).

Comment: Please include a sample of data that would make this reproducible

Comment: Your colon notation is making a sequence of values between the value of `tp1` and that of `tp4` and then taking the mean of that sequence.  Compare the result from what you did, `mtcars %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(mean1 = mean(mpg:cyl))`, vs making a vector of values for `mean()`, `mtcars %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(mean1 = mean(c(mpg, cyl)))`.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest tidying your data - seems like you should have one column each named `tp`, `ocb`, and `gl`, and a `key` column with values 1 to 4. Then you can group by `key` and not have to use `rowwise` at all.

Comment: This paper by Hadley Wickam might be useful to start with for tidying your data: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf